# The difference between Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer-2010

What is the difference between purchasing Visual Studio 2010 Express, and downloading Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?

Although I created a company website using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express (I love this product!), I'm not an experienced programmer.  But I'm wondering if Visual Studio 2010 Express is just as good, or better, and if it will do the same things as VWD.

I just can't google any good links that compares the two.

Comment: You don't purchase Visual Studio 2010 Express. All the Express versions are a free download. One of those is Visual Web Developer Express. Are you talking about VS 2010 Professional?

Comment: Instead of Google, did you consider looking on the Microsoft web site? http://www.microsoft.com/express, http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express, and then click the compare button.

Comment: Purchasing Visual Studio 2010 Express? There is no single VS2010E product: they're all separate installs, one of them being VWD2010E. Did you mean to ask for the difference between purchasing VS2010 Professional and using the separate Express products, or did you mean to ask for the difference between VWD2010E and one of the other Express products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has it:

[MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO - microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products)

and Definition of

[Microsoft Visual Studio Express - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express)

Just click on learn more in each product to see their  differences.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Biz, all.  I asked the question incorrectly.  After I looked at how I worded the question, it was too late to edit.  Nevertheless, thank you for the answer, and John, thank you for the link.  I definitely need to get my VWD back up and running after this PC Recovery.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Jason: Glad you got an answer, but just for future reference, it should *never* be too late to edit one of your own questions. In fact, doing so is highly encouraged on Stack Overflow, whether to correct a mistake, include additional information, or whatever else you might think of that could help get a better answer. The edit link should be under the post, right above the tags.

Comment: I never realized that until now.  Thanks for pointing that out, Cody.

Answer (score 0):

On the **"Visual Studio Express** 2010" disk VS2010Express.iso which I downloaded from Microsoft it turned out that Visual Studio Express consist of:

Visual C#,
Visual Basic,
Visual C++,
**"Visual Web developer".**

So to answer the original question here I think that Visual Web developer is one part of the whole disk called Visual Studio. But don't go there if you do not have to:

I am currently upgrading from Visual Studio 2008 because of the bug in .Net 2.0 / 3.5 related to not being able to work with (not recognizing) Internet Explorer 10, but now I get bugs related to App_GlobalResources. The whole Globalization function just does not work anymore. I am in a Hackathon nightmare of 48 hours trying to survive. I think that MS wanted to get you all on board with the free express edition but it is payback time now. I think I am going back to Uniface which is upward compatible. Once again, there is no such thing as free!!!